# Why are power spectrum plots $l^2 P(l)$ instead of just $P(l)$?

Tags: cosmology, fourier-transform, cosmic-microwave-background, spherical-harmonics

Why is it typically plotted $l^2 P(l)$, or $l(l+1) P(l)$, vs $l$ instead of just $P(l)$ in power spectrum plots?

For example, we can see it in this plot found in *Introduction to Gravitational Lensing* by *Massimo Meneghetti*:

[image: l^2 P(l)]

Another example would be the Cosmic Microwave Background power spectrum, where it is typically plotted $l(l+1) C_l$.